# Add Field To Custom WP Login Form

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom login form that I display on a page using the following:

```
        $my_login_args = apply_filters( 'my_login_page_args', array(
            'echo'           => true,
            'redirect'       => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
            'form_id'        => 'my_login_form',
            'label_username' => esc_html__( 'Email Address' ),
            'label_password' => esc_html__( 'Password' ),
            'label_remember' => esc_html__( 'Remember Me' ),
            'label_log_in'   => esc_html__( 'Sign In' ),
            'id_username'    => 'user_login',
            'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
            'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
            'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
            'remember'       => true,
            'value_username' => NULL,
            'value_remember' => false
        ) );
        wp_login_form( $my_login_args ); ?>
```

I need to pass a custom variable ($my_custom_id) stored in the login page through to the redirected page a user sees after login. Is there any way to append the URL with this variable using POST or GET or is the best solution to add this as a hidden field in the form?

Also, in terms of adding an extra field to the form I've tried adding a custom input box to the form using

```
add_action('login_form','my_added_login_field');
function my_added_login_field(){
    //Output your HTML
?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_extra_field">My extra field<br>
        <input type="text" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="my_extra_field" name="my_extra_field_name"></label>
    </p>
<?php
}
```

However this only adds the field to the main Wordpress login and not my custom form. Any thoughts on how best to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You can you add custom field in login form at top, bottom, and in middle.

I have added login field in login_form_middle.

For Reference https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L390

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

```
 /*
 You can use these hooks as well to place your fields    
 login_form_bottom - login_form_top - login_form_middle
 */

 add_filter('login_form_middle','my_added_login_field');
 function my_added_login_field(){
     //Output your HTML
     $additional_field = '<div class="login-custom-field-wrapper"">
         <label for="my_extra_field">My extra field<br>
         <input type="text" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="my_extra_field" name="my_extra_field_name"></label>
     </div>';

     return $additional_field;
 }
```